# <apex:input> value not being passed to controller

Tags: apex, controller

I am setting up value to apex:input using JS as below.

```
          document.getElementById('{!$Component.street_number}').value = val;
          document.getElementById('{!$Component.street_number}').innerHTML = val;
```

I see the value being displayed on the page, but when i click submit the value is not being passed to the controller.

Here is the field

```
           <td class="slimField"><apex:input id="street_number" disabled="true" StyleClass="form-     control" value="{!StreetNumber}"/> </td>
                    <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><apex:input id="route" disabled="true" StyleClass="form-control" value="{!Address}"/></td>
```

i have these fields defined as public variable in the controller as well.

```
  public String StreetNumber{get;set;}
public String Address{get;set;}
public String City{get;set;}
```

Comment: Setting `.value = val` should be sufficient there is no need to set the innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it is the behaviour but when i removed disabled = true from the field, i was able to access the values.

Comment: This is standard behavior - disabled form controls are not submitted with the form. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled

Comment: but using javascript, i am enabling the field and adding value to it before submitting.

Comment: That isn't demonstrated anywhere in your example code above. That said, any disabled form elements still are not submitted with the form. The presence of the `disabled` attribute on the element, makes the element disabled. In your javascript, you should be leveraging `.removeAttribute('disabled')` to completely remove that attribute from the element in the DOM.